# Does setting a variable as an operation store the operation or the value?

Tags: php

Consider the following in PHP:

```
$var = 3 * 5

echo $var //15
```

Is the value 15 stored or 3 * 5?

If the latter is stored I guess it would be a performance-issue if more complex operations are stored in a variable and needs to be ran every time the variable value printed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stored as the value, not the expression.

Comment: Stringht and functional answer. +1. BTW @Joshep, take a few minutes to read this, it may help you clear any doubt http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: @Márcio: I'd also add this: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: The real fun comes when you consider what would happen if it really did store the expression. A line such as `$var = $var * 3;` would be *mind blowing*.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP interpreter executes the calculation and stores the result into the variable. You will find this is the case with most languages.